# Получение данных только авторизованного пользователя из firebase через android studio

Tags: android, автоматизация, firebase-android

сейчас делаю приложение, где нужно сохранять записи в firebase через android studio, но нужно сохранять и получить эти записи, только авторизованного(через email и password, или через google аккаунт )и только его записи. В данное время сохраняю и получаю эти записи, но не знаю как будет происходить, если авторизоваться через другой телефон и с другим аккаунтом. А вопрос такое, в firebase уже так можно получить данные авторизованные пользователя и только его записи или нужно же прописать правила:

```
{
   "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

или же ref.child(id пользователя или что вроде этого).child(записи).child(конкретная запись)?
Хотелось понять, как сделать чтобы пользователь получал только его записи, если потом авторизовался через emailpassword, а потом авторизовался и получал те свои записи, а наоборот. Чтобы два аккаунта были связаны.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/role-based-access
Проверьте является ли пользователь автором записи ```request.auth.uid == resource.data.field_name```. request.auth - информация о пользователе которая приходит с запросом, request.resource.data - информация которая приходит от пользователя (например, новый документ или обновление существующего), resource.data - информация в БД (можно получать доступ к полям существующего документа к которому идёт запрос). Во время записи нужно создавать поле с uid пользователя.

Comment: Ну я использую же realtime datebase, а тут firestore, про request и resource не знаю не чего. Наверное придется делать так :

Comment: ref=  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("note"); uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();  ref.child(uid).child("запись"). То есть каждая запись будет иметь uid - id - пользователя